# Query differences between two tables with identical definitions

Tags: oracle, data-synchronization

I have two tables, `A` and `B` with identical columns. Table `B` can contain some rows where data are different from `A`. How can I write a query that shows rows that should be inserted into `B`, deleted from `B`, or updated in `B` to make the tables contain identical data?

this is the what i want:
I have two tables, A and B with identical data, duplicate data, incomplete data records. Table C is target table for all the data of A and B. then first I need take count of how many insert (without duplicates records and incomplete records), delete (additional duplicate data records and incomplete records), update (find incomplete data records and tally with other table records)?

#### table A

| col1 | col2pk | Col3 uniq |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aa | AA | 111 |
| bb | BB | 222 |
| null | CC | 333 |
| null | DD | 444 |
| ee | EE | 555 |
| hh | HH | 555 |

#### tableB

| col1 | col2pk | col3 uniq |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ff | FF | 666 |
| hh | HH | 999 |
| cc | GG | 888 |
| dd | NULL | null |
| cc | CC | 333 |
| aa | AA | 111 |

#### tableC (answer)

| col1 | col2pk | col3 uniq |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aa | AA | 111 |
| cc | CC | 333 |
| cc | GG | 888 |
| hh | HH | 999 |
| ff | FF | 666 |
| hh | HH | 555 |
| ee | EE | 555 |
| null | DD | 444 |
| bb | BB | 222 |

identical datfrom A and B

Expecting Answers

- insert count(*) is **09** -> (without delete 3 records)
- update count (*) is **1** -> null,CC,333 from cc,CC,333
- delete count(*) is **3** -> dd,null,null and null,cc,333 and aa,AA,111

Could we take table query through each data records count for insert, delete, update?

Comment: Please provide your tables and data in a fiddle - dbfiddle.uk - it's not good practice to expect others to do this for you - help us to help you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something of the sort like this to generate a row hash (this uses the [`MD5()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions183.htm) but there are other hashing functions that reduce chances for collision as well):

```
SELECT STANDARD_HASH((Column1 || '||' || Column2 || '||' || Column3), 'MD5') AS RowHash -- Add all columns together inside the MD5 function
FROM TableA
```

Ideally you'll want to add this as a [**virtual column**](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-virtual-column/) (or **generated** to maximize performance, and it's potentially indexable but you'd have to look into that further) or create views on top `TableA` and `TableB` with this column, that way you can the join on it like this:

```
INSERT INTO TableB
SELECT TableA.*
FROM TableA
LEFT JOIN TableB
    ON TableA.RowHash = TableB.RowHash
WHERE TableB.RowHash IS NULL -- Where there is no row in TableB that matched this row in TableA
```

The above assumes you don't have a **unique** field or **primary key** that you can use to relate the rows between `TableA` and `TableB`. Same idea can be applied to generate your `DELETE` and `UPDATE` statements. If you don't have a **key** field to relate the tables, then your `UPDATE` statement will likely have to be handled as a `DELETE` for the old row and `INSERT` for the updated row, otherwise if you do have a **key** field then your predicate for the `UPDATE` statement would be `WHERE TableA.KeyField = TableB.KeyField AND TableA.RowHash <> TableB.RowHash`.

Comment: Thank you. but expected query is different. logic is correct 40%.

Comment: @diljaya Sorry I don't follow, could you please clarifying what's incorrect or where you're still stuck?

Comment: @J.D Thank you for the your answer. but i stuck on count taking query.

Comment: @diljaya If you want to know just number of rows count then replace `SELECT TableA.*` with `SELECT COUNT(*)`.